# Is “'the most tawdry’ race-baiting” ungrammatical?

Tags: grammar, adjectives

When I was transcribing the following sentence of Time magazine’s (September 1st issue) article ’”The Tragedy of Ferguson”;

> “We elected a black man with a Muslim name to be President. What other
>   country would do that? The conversation has been blunted by the
>   President himself in the face of some of **the most tawdry** race-baiting
>   since Selma.”

the alarm of MS Word grammar checker popped out on the desktop giving the following suggestion, and demanding correction;

> “Comparative Use: When comparing with a one-syllable adjective and
>   “er” or “est” to the end of adjective, do not use “more” or “most”.
>   When comparing with a two syllable adjective, add “or” or “est” in
>   addition to the adjective. Instead of: This star is more bright,
>   consider, This star is brightest.

Did the writer neglected “er /est” on one /two-syllable-word rule, or “most tawdry” is perfectlly acceptable, and I should dismiss grammar checker warnings?

Comment: Bisyllables ending in /i/ can swing both ways, especially if they have an internal /dr/ cluster like _tawdry_ /'tɔdri/. _More easy_ is much rarer than _easier_, which is practically fixed, but _more tawdry_ seems easier than _tawdrier_, which is bound to trap some readers as _taw-drier_ and get them wondering what the hell "taw" is  and why it needs to be dried. Writers and editors have to consider a lot of things.

Comment: @John Lawler Doctors hope to have a cure for the internal /dr/ cluster by the end of the decade.

Comment: @John Lawler. I don't understand 'internal/dr/cluster. What does it mean?

Comment: The word "tawdry" containse the consonant cluster /dr/. That is, there is a /d/ sound followed by an /r/ sound, without a vowel in between them. That's common in English and not in Japanese, which must have a vowel between consonants. The symbols inside slashes represent English pronunciation, not spelling.

Comment: _Tawdry_ would seem to be the only bilsyllable adjective with an internal /dr/ ending in /i/.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

"Most tawdry since" is a perfectly reasonable qualifier, comparing this instance to all others since the cited time or incident.

Microsoft Word's rules are applied rather mindlessly, and are often inappropriate for real-world writing. Take them as suggestions to be considered -- and possibly rejected -- NOT as expert advice. Or turn them off entirely, since in my experience they're less than helpful.

Answer (score 1):

A search with [Google nGram viewer](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=most%20tawdry%2Ctawdriest&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cmost%20tawdry%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Ctawdriest%3B%2Cc0) indicates that both *tawdriest* and *most tawdry* are in common use today.

MS Word's grammar checker is good for spotting careless mistakes like using *your* instead of *you're*, but it should never be treated as authoritative.